# How can I update my interface builder project to current constraints?

Tags: interface-builder, autolayout, uistoryboard

I have a bunch of constraints set up that work well at run time, but aren't reflected in my storyboard because of small errors in positioning the views. 
Is there any way I can have my storyboard / xib reset all views to acknowledge the constraints I have set up?

If this was already asked, I apologize. I'd expect this has been asked, but my queries aren't returning helpful results.

Answer (score 0):

There's an option when you click the `Resolve AutoLayout Issues` tab in Interface Builder called `Update Frames`. Also there is the opposite (and more commonly used) `Update Constraints` to move the constraints to whatever your frame is set to.

[image: "Fix frames"]