# Why constraints apply to uiview doesn't reflect in storyboard?

Tags: ios

When i set UIView in storyboard and applying constraints on that but after that it doesn't set according to the constraints whichever i set. After that i restart XCode and open storyboard, my changes are reflect their in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you need to update view frames after adding constraints if the frame has changed based on your constraints. If you select a view and go to Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Update Frames (under either the selected view or all views)

See:
[How can I update my interface builder project to current constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977532/how-can-i-update-my-interface-builder-project-to-current-constraints)